# Issue with declaring variable without overriding the variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Inside of a function I have to declare two local float variables: `jAxis` and `jumpValue` at the start.  `jAxis` is immediately assigned a variable in the start while `jumpValue` is just `float jumpValue;`

I have an `if` statement later in the code that has the `jumpValue` used in inside of it.  However, `jumpValue` should never be unassigned a value before getting to this point.  The compiler disagrees with an error saying `use of unassigned local variable jumpValue` for the `Vector3` calculation near the bottom.

Here is my relevant code:

```
void JumpHandler()
{

    float jAxis = Input.GetAxis("Jump");
    float jumpValue;

    //if pressed
    if (jAxis > 0)
    {
        bool isGrounded = CheckGrounded();

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            jumpValue = jAxis; 
            if (!jumpPressed)
            {
                jumpPressed = true; //Pressed jump
            }
        }
        else
        {
            jumpValue = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (jumpPressed)
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, Math.Abs(jumpValue) * jumpForce * 1, 0) , ForceMode.VelocityChange);//Absolute value to prevent weird cases of negative jAxis
        //jump key not pressed
        jumpPressed = false;
        jumpValue = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        jumpPressed = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions - please search for error message and ["definitely assigned"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_assignment_analysis) to pick duplicate that explain your exact case.

Comment: I didn't do float jumpValue = 0 at the start because that will always make my jumpValue 0 for when I need it in the Vector3 assignment.  jumpPressed also starts out as false for when this portion of the program runs.

Comment: Every time `JumpHandler` is called, `jumpValue`, because it's a local variable, is unset until it's set that time the method is being run. It's possible -- and in this case only possible -- for the `rb.AddForce...` line to be run without `jumpValue` being set that time `JumpHandler` is being run.

Comment: You're right, I understand *why* it won't run, but I don't know how to get around it for the purpose of my code.  The only way I can think of is to declare jumpValue outside of the scope of the function, but I was really hoping there was another way to declare it without resetting the value on it.

Comment: What I meant by the Vector3 assignment was this:
new Vector3(0, Math.Abs(jumpValue) * jumpForce * 1, 0)

Comment: `but I was really hoping there was another way to declare it without resetting the value on it. ` It definitely needs to be in a different scope.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense for the `if(jumpPressed)` block to be exclusive with the `if (jAxis > 0)` block. Remove the `else` before `if (jumpPressed)`.

Also, you should intialize `jumpValue` to `0f` because the compiler can't recognize on its own that `jumpPressed` is only true when `jumpValue` is set.

You don't need the else block to set `jumpPressed` to false because it's already going to be false if it's in that block.

Altogether, this could look like so:

```
void JumpHandler()
{

    float jAxis = Input.GetAxis("Jump");
    float jumpValue = 0f;

    //if pressed
    if (jAxis > 0)
    {
        bool isGrounded = CheckGrounded();

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            jumpValue = jAxis; 
            if (!jumpPressed)
            {
                jumpPressed = true; //Pressed jump
            }
        }
        else
        {
            jumpValue = 0;
        }
    }

    if (jumpPressed)
    {
        rb.AddForce(
                //Absolute value to prevent weird cases of negative jAxis
                new Vector3(0, Mathf.Abs(jumpValue) * jumpForce, 0),
                ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        //jump key not pressed
        jumpValue = 0;
        jumpPressed = false;
    }
}
```

This produces output like this (with a dummy method for `CheckGrounded` that returns `true` once):

[image]

Comment: Doing it this way always results in jumpValue being 0 for my calculation.  Also, code was removed for the post which is why there's weird formatting.

Comment: @LoganMcPhillips Works for me (see gif added in answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where `JumpHandler` is called from but the entire calculation using `bool` flags etc makes little sense to me.

- There is no need to store the value meanwhile in the local variable `jumpValue`. You only want to use it in exactly one spot so simply pass in the according value `jAxis` directly.
- Since you check `jAxis > 0` right before, the `Mathf.Abs` is redundant.
- You are postponing the actual execution of jump to the next time `jumpHandler` is called again when `jAxis <= 0` .. was this intended? If not simply directly execute the jump when requried conditions are fulfilled. There is no need for a `jumpPressed` flag.
- Since you allow `AddForce` only if `CheckGrounded` passing in `jAxis` as force multiplier might also result in unexpected behavior. This is a one-time call since supposedly in the next frame (or wherever you call it) it should not be grounded anymore. The `jAxis` value however might be very small (depending on what type of axis you have there).

As far as I can tell your code does pretty much the same as this (without the postponing of the jump and simply passing in `jumpForce * 1` instead of `jAxis`)

```
void JumpHandler()
{
    float jAxis = Input.GetAxis("Jump");
    if(jAxis > 0 && CheckGrounded)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
}
```